# Is 8080 a dynamic port or static.?

Tags: networking

There is lot of confusion
IANA suggests that dynamic port range should be 49000 to 65535
Though 8080 is used by many web services like Apache Tomcat, Proxy Server, etc.. but i have doubt that it is static port

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port

Comment: Thanks Oli.. But i have already read the article about Ephemeral_port on wikipedia. My question is can we call 8080 port as a Static or Dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

You don't appear to understand what a dynamic port is. It is one which is allocated *by the system,* when you don't specify one yourself. If an application specifies the port itself, for example 8080, it is an example of static port usage.

Comment: Thanks EJP for your answer..